# Sharing Wordpress blog post on LinkedIn

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I have this code, to share my blog post to LinkedIn:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink());?>&source=testing" onClick="return popup(this, 'posts')" data-url="<?php echo the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"class="button share-social share-linkedin" title="Share on LinkedIn"></a>
```

It shows my blog title correctly in the share popup, but "source" is not displayed, and i am unable to show the blog post image in the Linkedin share popup?

Is it the correct way to give the PHP code inside the URL?

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

[Click to share](https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com)
Store the url that you need share in `$url` and then

```
<?php
$url=get_permalink();
?>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=".<?php echo $url; ?>.">Click to share</a>
```